# Best way to implement Browser's back button with React Router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router

I have a large React app, that has a simple React-Router layout:

```
routes = <Route path="/" component={MainComponent} >
<Route path="login" component={LoginContainer} />
<Route path="admin" component={AdminContainer} onEnter={requireAuth}/>
<Route path="registration" component={RegistrationContainer} />
```

```
<Router routes={routes} history={browserHistory}/>
```

The thing is in my ***/admin*** component there are a lot of other components.
I have a toolbar, for example you can click on Cars, Trucks and Users.

(keep in mind, everything is in /admin route)

So let's say a user, logs in, he is directed to /admin.
Then he clicks on Trucks, and checks some trucks, (he can open each truck item),
then he clicks on cars, checks some individual cars like McLaren.
Now he decides to click on a (browser's) back button, and to be returned from
McLaren to list of Cars, and if he clicks back button again he would be returned to Trucks (or whatever he visited before Cars).

How can I implement this, since everything is in ***/admin*** route?